# How Can I Configure the Gargantuan Android 12 Lockscreen Clock?

Tags: lock-screens, android-12

On Android 12, at least on Pixel devices, the lockscreen has a massive clock when there are no notifications — vertically, it takes up perhaps 2/3rds of the screen. I would rather the clock be smaller, akin to the one where there are one or more notifications showing on the lockscreen. I cannot find anything in the Settings app or the system Clock app's settings that controls this behavior.

Is there way to configure the lockscreen clock size?

Comment: Fully agree and that's what I noticed too.. Very irritating. If you enable unread notifications on lock screen and if they are there the clock becomes small//Also disable *always show time and info* in lock screen settings so that you don't have to see it always +1

Comment: My device is rooted and there doesn't seem to be any rooted method to achieve this (Pixel 4a)